# What game is this with colored tokens, a dice, and what looks like a spoon?

Tags: identify-this-game, dice

I bought it secondhand and it came with one red die with a devil, a woman, a man, a club, a fan, and a wooden paddle, and each side is numbered. It also came with 6 red chips, 5 yellow chips, and 4 blue chips. Finally it came with what looks like a little metal flat spoon. All of these things came in a small box labeled "Couple Dice".

Does anyone know what this game is called and/or the rules?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Looks like it could be some variation of Tiddlywinks.

Comment: The drawings look Japanese. I tried searching plausible translations of "couple dice" in Japanese, but came up with nothing. How do these things fit into the box. Could there be parts missing, for example, if the top section holds dice, then there could be 3 dice missing.

Comment: It was bought in at a Japanese flea market!

Answer (score 1):

This might be a variant of a Japanese game known as Ohajiki. My understanding is that it was traditionally played with flatten marbles and is similar to tiddlywinks. The spoon and die suggest is might be some variation on the game.

Comment: Welcome to the site! Do you have images or links to the game to show pieces or it being played? It would help improve your answer.